# Session being cleared in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, filter, onactionexecuting

What happens to Session between the Session_Start call and OnActionExecuting in an ActionFilterAttribute.

For some reason, when I set something like this:

```
protected void Session_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Session["GoToBuyPage"] = true;
}
```

and try to access it here in the ActionFilterAttribute:

```
public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
{
    bool goToPage = (bool)Session["GoToBuyPage"];
```

it is always null. Any ideas why?

Answer (score -1):

There's no `Session` property of an `ActionFilterAttribute`. So I don't even know how your code compiles. The following works perfectly fine for me:

Action filter:

```
public class FooAttribute: ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        bool goToPage = (bool)filterContext.HttpContext.Session["GoToBuyPage"];
        filterContext.Result = new ContentResult
        {
            Content = goToPage.ToString()
        };
    }
}
```

Controller:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    [Foo]
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

`Session_Start`:

```
protected void Session_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Session["GoToBuyPage"] = true;
}
```